# Does the holodeck have to work extra hard for Geordi Laforge?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Geordi's visor is capable of seeing spectra outside of the normal human visual range. The holodeck creates its environment at least partly by creating actual holographic images. Such images would be simpler to simulate if they remained within that same visible spectrum. But this would not be as satisfying to Geordi as to most other participants.